# NodeJs Crypto failing to verify a Fido2 Public Key and Signature

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, cryptojs, passkey

Whilst trying to implement Passkey login using AWS Cognito, I found a guide written by AWS (https://github.com/aws-samples/webauthn-with-amazon-cognito/). It shows how to use lambda triggers to respond to challenges and to implement the flow. My solution uses React on the UI and ASP Net on the API and, though the demo code is a nodejs implementation using the library Fido2-Lib, I found I could implement almost the same in C# using the Fido2NetLib library.

Everything was going fine, all moving parts generally aligned around creating and parsing credentials, even the AWS lambdas for Cognito seemed to be playing nicely, until the crunch point came with logging in. I started to get `error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported` when the public key and signature were verified. I looked into this thinking first that the key was in an unexpected format. I realised that the Fido2-Lib in the demo code outputs a PEM format key, whereas the Fido2NetLib doesn't provide that option and instead provides COSE format CBOR object (inline with the standard - tho, as I write this I assume the PEM key from Fido2-Lib is also a CBOR inside the PEM format).

I double checked the contents of the key and ensured they were all pretty standard and acceptable by NodeJS Crypto

```
1: 2 - key type Elliptic Curve format 
3: -7 - algorithm used ES256 
-1: 1 - curve type P-256 
-2: buffer(32) - x co-ordinate 
-3: buffer(32) - y co-ordinate
```

using that information, I wrote a test program to just test the verify method, and tried adding PEM format (the '---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ----') no joy, I tried, taking the contents of the CBOR map in the private key and (having learned about DER format) create a DER format key, which I believe crypto can accept, using the following sample code, but no joy, the same UNSUPPORTED ROUTINE error.

```
const coseKey = Buffer.from(publicKeyCredJSON.publicKey, 'base64');

// Parse COSE key
const parsedKey = cbor.decodeFirstSync(coseKey);

// Extract necessary information
const keyType = parsedKey.get(1); // Key type
const algorithm = parsedKey.get(3); // Algorithm

const xCoord = parsedKey.get(-2);
const yCoord = parsedKey.get(-3);// Key value

// Convert key data to buffer
const publicKey = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from([0x04]), xCoord, yCoord]);

// Sample data and signature to verify (replace with your actual data and signature)
const rawAuthnrData = Buffer.from(challengeAnswerJSON.response.authenticatorData, 'base64');
const rawClientData = Buffer.from(challengeAnswerJSON.response.clientDataJSON, 'base64');

// Create verifier
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');

// Provide data
verifier.update(rawAuthnrData);
verifier.update(rawClientData);

// Verify signature
const isValid = verifier.verify(publicKey, challengeAnswerJSON.response.signature, 'base64');`
```

I appreciate this is a nebulous topic, and having tried modifying the verify call to crypto to pass more parameters, understand the format of the key from Fido2NetLib and how it differs to Fido2-Lib I thought I'd reach out on here to see if I'm bumping into something silly, others have already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true nodejs crypto accepts the PEM and DER formats defined by OpenSSL (which it uses internally); technically these are not the only possible PEM and DER formats, but in practice they are or until recently were the de-facto standards *for cryptography-related data*. Traditionally it defaulted to PEM and you needed to explicitly specify format=DER and in some cases type, but OpenSSL 3's new API (which your version is apparently using) may have changed this.

However, I don't know where you 'learned' about DER, but **your posted code does not create anything even remotely similar to DER**. It does convert the EC *point* to an X9-and-SEC1 format, which is the most common standard and is used *in* OpenSSL's and thus nodejs' PEM and DER formats, but it is not by itself either PEM or DER or even a valid key.

If you have nodejs 16 up, which I expect you do if you have OpenSSL 3, it *also* supports JWK format as used in JOSE, and this is (not accidentally) much closer to COSE. Try `{format:'jwk', key:{perRFC7518}}` where the minmal [RFC7518 spec for EC public key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.2) is

```
{kty:'EC',crv:'P-256',x:bufferx.encode('base64url'),y:buffery.encode('base64url')}
```

For older nodejs you'll need in principle to construct the DER format defined in [RFC5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480.html) (or its PEM equivalent, but that's more work and no benefit); this includes an outer header, an AlgorithmIdentifier containing id-ecPublicKey and the curve OIDs, and a BIT STRING containing the point in SEC1 format (same as X9 with the exclusion of hybrid, which is not an issue for you). However as the point length is fixed per curve, *for a given curve* this DER structure is actually a fixed prefix plus the point, and you can copy the fixed prefix from a throwaway key (also for P-256!) you create with either nodejs or OpenSSL (they are the same thing here).

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, I'll try the JWK approach. But for my own sanity, a COSE public key as a base64 string, in PEM format, so with the header and footer added (the '---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ----') should work in crypto, yes? I feel like I've been chasing my own tail on this for a few weeks now.

Comment: @Matt: No. First your key is a public key not a private key. Then the COSE format (for either key) uses CBOR encoding which is different from DER or BER, of the COSE structure which is different from either SPKI or PKCS8. The PEM type BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY is only for a BER-usually-DER encoding of PKCS8-unencrypted or (rarely) its RFC5958 extension (see RFC7468 section 10) and putting a false label doesn't make it correct. This is like putting a cow turd in a box with a label that says "gold bar inside" -- anyone who opens the box to get a gold bar is badly disappointed.

Comment: Well I finally got there 

I've marked this response as the answer as it lead me to the final success. I tried using the JWK approach, and in doing so learned more about what crypto.verify accepts, and how sometimes you need to call createPublicKey in order to get a KeyObject, or at least to better understand the parameters in the flow. This got closer, but didn't work so I tried to think how can I get a DER or PEM format key instead of CBOR, given how even broken into a JWK it was still failing to verify.

Comment: I double checked the webauthn flow and documentation and realised that there's another way to get an alternate format key instead of the default CBOR. Thankfully, the web standard advanced to the point of [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AuthenticatorAttestationResponse/getPublicKey](providing a function to give a DER format), precisely to avoid needing CBOR functions. So with that in hand, and knowledge about setting up a format DER key with crypto.createPublicKey, checking the params required for hashing and signature check and boom. Success! Thanks Dave :)